# Releasing updates for android application on playstore

Tags: android

I've a app released on `google play store`. Now i want to provide an update for it. All the users using the older version must somehow get notification of the new update available on play store and must also update it if update automatically flag is set.

How can i do that? Any help to the guide regarding providing updates for application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Or as Scott phrases it, you dont *need* to. Simply upload your update to the Play store and Google will handle all of that automatically for you. That's how the store works.

Comment: Well, technically you _could_ do all that messy stuff yourself, with a lot of effort.  The point is that you don't _need_ to, the store does it for you.